# Normalize nested json Using JSONPATH

Tags: java, jsonpath

I Have a nested json which i want to normalize/flatten using JsonPath in Java.

My JSON is as below:

```
{
    "FamilyName": "Smith",
    "City":"NY",
    "Members":[{
        "Name" : "jacob",
        "Age" : "19",
        "Gender" : "Male"
    },{
        "Name" : "Sophia",
        "Age" : "29",
        "Gender" : "Female"
    }]

}
```

What I want to retrieve is Normalised json, as below:

```
[   
    {
        "FamilyName": "Smith",
        "City":"NY",
        "Name" : "jacob",
        "Age" : "19",
        "Gender" : "Male"
    },
    {
        "FamilyName": "Smith",
        "City":"NY",
        "Name" : "Sophia",
        "Age" : "29",
        "Gender" : "Female"
    }
]
```

Using JsonPath, What i can do is retrieve the Members list and loop over it, to form normalised data MySelf. But I feel for a huge data it wont be efficient.
Is there any efficient way in jsonpath using which i can get desired output ?

**Updated**

Sample code:[This is just a sample code not the actual one. I just tried to put my use case here.]

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.ReadContext;

public class TestApp {
    static JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    static List<String> columnList = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(
            "$.FamilyName-String",
            "$.City-String"
    );
    static String arrayPath = "$.Members";

    static List<String> arrayColumnList = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(
            "$.Name-String",
            "$.Age-Integer",
            "$.Gender-String"
            );

    static Map<String, Class<?>> dataTypeMap = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>() {
        {
            put("String", String.class);
            put("Integer", Integer.class);
        }
    };

    static String data = "{\"FamilyName\": \"Smith\",\"City\":\"NY\",\"Members\":[{ \"Name\" : \"jacob\",   \"Age\" : \"19\",   \"Gender\" : \"Male\"},{    \"Name\" : \"Sophia\",  \"Age\" : \"29\",   \"Gender\" : \"Female\"}]}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DocumentContext parsedDocumentContext = ParserFactory.getJsonParseContext().parse(data);
        JsonArray processedList= processData(parsedDocumentContext);
        System.out.println(processedList);
        // Do further operations 

    }

    public static JsonArray processData(DocumentContext parsedDocumentContext) {

        JsonObject values = new JsonObject();
        for (String eachColumn : columnList) {
            String array[] = eachColumn.split("-");
            String eachField[] = array[0].split("\\.");
            values.addProperty(eachField[eachField.length - 1], (String) parsedDocumentContext.read(array[0], dataTypeMap.get(array[1])).toString());
        }

        JsonArray allValues = new JsonArray();
        if (null == arrayPath || arrayPath.isEmpty()) {
            allValues.add(values);
            return allValues;
        }
        List<Map<String, Object>> nested = parsedDocumentContext.read(arrayPath, List.class);
        for (Map<String, Object> eachMembers : nested) {
            //List eachValue = new ArrayList<Object>(values);
            JsonObject eachValue = jsonParser.parse(values.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
            ReadContext readContext = JsonPath.parse(eachMembers);
            for (String eachColumn : arrayColumnList) {
                String array[] = eachColumn.split("-");
                String eachField[] = array[0].split("\\.");
                eachValue.addProperty(eachField[eachField.length - 1], readContext.read(array[0], dataTypeMap.get(array[1])).toString());
            }
            allValues.add(eachValue);
        }
        return allValues;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: can you show the code what have you tried?

Comment: @Deadpool I have added sample code. just as a reminder, in the above code i tried to put my use case all in one place and it is not the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson library to map JSON to Java Object, implement a converter to other desired Java model object and then export it as JSON. You can consider using google Gson as well.
Though if you code proper custom implementation, there is noway it can be beaten with robust library.